# Pandas count of rolling return outcomes, within a rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

Python beginner here ! I'm doing some work on probabilities and looking at a stock market index. I need to be able to count the number of times an index drops 20% within a 3 year period, but across a 12 yr period.

For example - my data starts in 2008. If I pick a 3 yr rolling window I want to know how many times the market dropped from that starting level to a level 20% lower. Then I want to roll my start date forward a day and count again.

I have completed the project that counts the number of times the index drops 20% (or more) at the end of the 3 yr period (over a 12 yr dataset), but I cannot fathom how to add this extra level of "counts". I need to fix the start date and calc the return and then add to count if the return is less than -20%. Then repeat for all possible start dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=N+1)
df['Count_B20'] = (df['Last_Price'].rolling(indexer, min_periods=1)
                                       .apply(lambda window: (window <
                                                              
df['B20'].iloc[window.index.min()]).sum()))
```

df['B20'] is my barrier level column (20% in question) df['Last Price'] is the last price over the range

Did exactly what I needed !